What's so funny in Drax's words?
In Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3 (2023), Starhawk gave the Guardians of the Galaxy red uniforms to wear so
they could move through the Orgo without attracting attention:

Drax: This isn't my color.
Starhawk: What did you say?
Drax: It clashes with my eyes.

Everybody laughs.
What's so funny in Drax's words?

It's not necessarily in his words. Caring about appearance clashes with traditional ideas of "toughness". Since Drax is like "muscle" he might not be expected to care all that much, so it's funny because it eases tension in the plot, going against expectations and societal norms in a humorous way. Have you also considered tone?

Better off asking this in our [scifi.se] site.
